# Move all files in a directory in a subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I can't find a quick solution for this simple problem: I' ve got this tree:

```
fatherDir
   -File1.txt
   -SomeFile.txt
    ...
   - A name.txt
   -sonDir
```

I want to move all the files in fatherDir inside fatherDir/SonDir.

```
mv * sonDir
```

Since sonDir is inside fatherDir, I get an error.

How to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all files in `fatherDir` rather than using `*` (which gives you the `sonDir` too)

```
find fatherDir -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} fatherDir/sonDir \+
```

The `{}` will be replaced by each filename found, and all will be moved to the target directory.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to use grep in combination with xargs:

```
ls -A | egrep -v sonDir | xargs -i mv {} sonDir
```

- first list all files and folders in the current directory (ie. fatherDir) with `ls`
- make sure to read out hidden files as well with the `-A` flag
- `egrep -v` lets you exclude sonDir of the printed output
- create command line from standard input with `xargs` and replace `{}` with regarding filename. Option `-i` is required here!

That's it! I use this approach rather frequently since it lets you exclude not only a folder, but different folders and files at the same time. In case you want to exclude e.g. `sonDir` `daughterDir` and `nephew.file` you can do so by simply specifying `egrep -v '(sonDir|daughterDir|nephew.file)'`, the rest of above shown command stays the same... and there is lots of variations!

Answer (score -1):

Does it matter? The Move still happens. What you get is more of a warning. You can redirect the stderr to /dev/null. Also, if it still bothers you, use find as explained by slhck or something like this:

```
mv `ls * | grep -v sonDir` sonDir
```

Comment: This fails if any file contains a space in its name, e.g. with "A name.txt" as in the example above.